# How to shorten url when sharing a webpage from my website on social media?

Tags: javascript, short-url

How to shorten url when sharing a webpage from my website on social media?
I hope it can be done with javascript and apis, I've checked the bitly api, but don't know how to get starting.
Thanks.

Comment: https://developers.google.com/url-shortener/v1/getting_started

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have 2 useful resources for you:

This one for google url shortener: http://www.i-visionblog.com/2014/07/google-url-shortener-api-javascript.html

And this one for bit.ly: https://bdhacker.wordpress.com/2010/03/30/dynamically-use-bitly-in-your-site-easiest-way/

> First, you need an account on http://bit.ly. To create one, go to the
>   site and register.
>
> Once you’ve registered, login and go to your Account page. There, you
>   will find your API key.

Put this in your HTML HEAD:

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="http://bit . ly/javascript-api.js?version=latest&login=******&apiKey=*****************"></script>
```

(remove spaces in bit.ly url. stackoverflow doesn't allow to post answers with that url)

---

Put this before `</body>`:

```
<script>
    // Bit.ly API
    BitlyCB.shortenResponse = function(data) {
            var sss = '';
            var first_result;
            // Results are keyed by longUrl, so we need to grab the first one.
            for     (var r in data.results) {
                    first_result = data.results[r]; break;
            }
            sss = first_result["shortUrl"].toString();
            document.getElementById("qlink").value = sss;
    }
    BitlyClient.shorten(window.location, 'BitlyCB.shortenResponse');
</script>
```

---

And this, somewhere in your page:

```
<h3>Link to this page</h3><br>
Use this link to tell others about this page! <input onclick = "this.select()" type = 'text' id = "qlink" style = "width:100%;">
```